# If i use app licensing on my app's update what happens to user already installed application?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I have an application and i want to use Android Market License as copy protection. If i use this on my app's next version what happens to my existing users if they update their apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the licensing API asks the Android Market whether or not the user has purchased the application and then returns the appropriate response, there shouldn't be an issue for users that have legitimately purchased your application through the Market. It should just do the license check and that should be it.